# PHP SoapClient request

Tags: php, soap, request

I'm trying to send a SOAP request to a newsletter service using [this WSDL](http://dev-service.go.mayoris.com/wcf/SubscriptionService.wsdl?wsdl).

Here's my PHP:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url, array(
    'login' => 'myusername',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'trace' => true
));

$client->AddSubscriber(
    new SoapParam('MyFirstName', 'FirstName'),
    new SoapParam('MyLastName', 'LastName'),
    new SoapParam('myemail@someaddress.com', 'Email')
);
```

I'm getting the exception:

```
End element 'Body' from namespace 'schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'LastName' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 156.
```

Here's what the service is expecting for AddSubscriber:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthHeader xmlns="admin.ekeryx.com">
      <Username>string</Username>
      <Password>string</Password>
      <AccountID>string</AccountID>
    </AuthHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <AddSubscriber xmlns="admin.ekeryx.com">
      <subscriber>
        <ID>string</ID>
        <FirstName>string</FirstName>
        <LastName>string</LastName>
        <Email>string</Email>
      </subscriber>
      <overwritable>boolean</overwritable>
    </AddSubscriber>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here's what's being sent:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="tempuri.org/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:AddSubscriber/>
            <LastName>MyLastName</LastName>
            <Email>myemail@someaddress.com</Email>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'm not very familar with SOAP, and I've been looking for documentation all over the place, but I can't seem to find a very good reference for what I'm doing.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated!

---

Thanks. Could you give me an example? I'm looking at the example on the PHP site that shows:

```
<?php
class SOAPStruct {
    function SOAPStruct($s, $i, $f) 
    {
        $this->varString = $s;
        $this->varInt = $i;
        $this->varFloat = $f;
    }
}
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "http://localhost/soap.php",
                                     'uri'      => "http://test-uri/"));
$struct = new SOAPStruct('arg', 34, 325.325);
$soapstruct = new SoapVar($struct, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "SOAPStruct", "http://soapinterop.org/xsd");
$client->echoStruct(new SoapParam($soapstruct, "inputStruct"));
?>
```

Are you saying I would have to create a Subscriber PHP class, assign all the vars `$this->FirstName = $first_name`, etc... and then put it in a SoapVar with encoding `SOAP_ENC_OBJECT`? How can I better represent the subscriber structure?

Comment: Please note, I have removed the http:// from all the URLs in the code in order to comply with the maximum of 1 hyperlink per post rule.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible Params subscriber and overwriteable

```
<soap:Body>
<AddSubscriber xmlns="admin.ekeryx.com">
  <subscriber>
    <ID>string</ID>
    <FirstName>string</FirstName>
    <LastName>string</LastName>
    <Email>string</Email>
  </subscriber>
  <overwritable>boolean</overwritable>
</AddSubscriber>
```

So you need to do some more complex construction by using SoapVar to represent the subsrciber structure.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php

Should look something like this i think, although youll want to check the XSD against the Soap:Body produced...

```
$subscriber = new StdClass();
$subscriber->ID = 'myid';
$subscriber->FirstName = 'First';
$subscriber->LastName = 'Last';

$subscriber = new SoapParam(new SoapVar($subscriber, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, $type, $xsd), 'subscriber');
```

$type should be the type in the XSD/WSDL defeinition for the api and $xsd is the URI for the XSD.

I think that should do it but Ive only used native PHP libs once for EBay (it was a nightmare haha) and that was almost 2 years ago so im a little rusty.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while looking for a similar answer myself. I believe the issue you are having is that the following code will pass the login and password in the HTTP header not the SOAP header

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url, array(
    'login' => 'myusername',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'trace' => true
));
```

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
$headerbody = array('Token' => $someToken, 
                    'Version' => $someVersion, 
                    'MerchantID'=>$someMerchantId, 
                      'UserCredentials'=>array('UserID'=>$UserID, 
                                             'Password'=>$Pwd));
```